# Lists in dataframe columns - need to obtain an index in one column and use to to pull data from another column list

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with several columns. What I need to do is match data in a list in column `Name`, obtain the index, and use that index to search a list in column `Date` and grab the corresponding date to filter on.

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| [n1, n2, n3] | [date1, date2, date3] |

*e.g.*  if `Name === n2`, return index

*then:* `Date[index]` return date

*then:* `filter` on date

The table has thousands of rows with other columns (containing unique IDs and other data) so I'm looking for a solution to work on that scale.

This needs to be in Spark Scala, which I am very new in learning and I'm struggling to even print a value from the initial if statement. Any pointers or potential things to try would be massively appreciated.

I can access the list within the column using
`df.select($"name")`
and access a specific piece of data at an index using
`df.select($"name"(0))`

However, if I try:

```
for (x <- df.select($"name"){
   println("print anything")
}
```

the code looks like it executes (there are no errors) but I get nothing printed at all, not even just a string like I have above.

I've been trying to get even this simple(!) first bit to work for a good few days and have tried a number of solutions found here, but most solutions seem to throw a type error (e.g., I have a row and not a list). I don't understand this as I can pull data by specifying an index, so why is it unable to read the list and thinks it is a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you meant by `then: filter on date`, but this might help you achieve what you want to do.

If `df` was this dataset:

```
+------------+---------------------+
|Name        |Date                 |
+------------+---------------------+
|[n1, n2, n3]|[date1, date2, date3]|
+------------+---------------------+
```

Then this:

```scala
df.withColumn("newDate", expr("Date[find_in_set('n2', array_join(Name, ',')) - 1]"))
```

Gives this:

```
+------------+---------------------+-------+
|Name        |Date                 |newDate|
+------------+---------------------+-------+
|[n1, n2, n3]|[date1, date2, date3]|date2  |
+------------+---------------------+-------+
```

Which you can then `filter` or do what ever you like. Hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much, this is much more elegant than the knots I was creating! I have applied it to my data and it works beautifully. :)

The end point is to filter the data on the "newDate" and select only updated data - i.e. when lastUploadDate < newDate the row should be retained and passed to the next step in the process. This should be a massive step towards that! 
Thanks again, much appreciated! :)

Comment: No problem, good luck further